# *ngFor not working with my array when displaying on template

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have tried display content using  *ngFor both on a table and select components but nothing seems to work. could you please assist?
on my component i have this

```
public get locs(): Address[] {
        var addr: Address[] = [{ id: 0, priceQuickDelivery: 0, DeliveryTime: "3456", name: "samwel", price: 0 }];
        return addr;
    }
changeLocation(id: any) {
        console.log("locations id", id);

        this.currentLocation = this.locations.filter(f => {
            f.id == id
        })[0];
        console.log("selected location:", this.currentLocation);

    }
```

and on my template i have this:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let loc of locs">
                <td>value</td>
                <td>{{loc.name}}</td>
                <td>{{loc.id}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div >
        <select #SelectLocation (change)="changeLocation(SelectLocation.value)">
            <option value="0">Choose Location</option>
            <option *ngFor="let location of locs"> {{location}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

my Address model is as follows:

```
export class Address {
    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public price: number;
    public priceQuickDelivery: number;
    public DeliveryTime: string;
    constructor() { }
}
```

my output is as follow [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui0V3.png)

[image]

Comment: use `{{location.name}}`, else display [Object, Object]

Comment: In the `<option>` you need to specify any of the properties. If not it would interpolate to the complete object. Try `<option *ngFor="let location of locs"> {{location.name}}</option>`. It works in this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h22kyn

Comment: okay i figured out why there was an error, on a totally different <label></label> further along in my template i had an "undefined" property.i guess in angular this affects even the code before... and also.. yes i was to write location.name, too many edits/trials until i forgot that part

Answer (score 0):

You did not use property in `*ngFor` change to

```
<option *ngFor="let location of locs" value={{location.id}}> {{location.name}}</option>
```

Stackbliz demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6p9fbh

Comment: may be your api return empty so dropdown show empty

Answer (score 0):

As location is a list of objects

Using this `<option *ngFor="let location of locs"> {{location}}</option>` will not display anything as location is a object and you might be getting `[Object, Object]`

Instead use properties of location not the location itself i.e.

`<option *ngFor="let location of locs"> {{location.name}}</option>`

Surely it will populate your list

Comment: it had refused to popuate since i had a totally different error further down the template